# How to 'unassign' variables used for PlotPoints, which subsequently print as e.g. Charting`Private`pvar$727158

Tags: plotting, assignment, clear

I have a table of four insoluble equations, fceq, in terms of unassigned variables,

```
Subscript[fc, i], Subscript[μ, i].
```

I am using contour plots to visualise them:

```
cplots = Table[ContourPlot[Evaluate[fceq[[i]]], {Subscript[fc, i], 0, 
1}, {Subscript[μ, i], 1, 3.8}, PlotPoints -> 260], {i, 1, 4}]
```

That works fine but it has an unpleasant side effect. After running this, printing Subscript[fc, 1], for example, returns

```
Charting`Private`pvar$727158
```

instead of simply fc_1, and similarly for mu_1. I want to remove these assignments so I can use these variables again, but Clear[Subscript[fc, 1]] doesn't work. What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: This is a good reason not to use subscripts except for display purposes. It leads to no end of headaches otherwise.

Comment: I agree! I usually avoid subs but in my current work I have lots of tables of equations and I couldn't figure out how to automatically index variables without using subs. Is there a way to do, e.g.

    Table[xi[t]-> i Sin[t],{i,1,imax}]

such that the loop knows to isolate the 'i' in 'xi' and change it with the index? I want the output to be

    {x1[t]->1 Sin[t], x2[t]->2 Sin[t], ....}

This is straightforward if the 'i' is dropped to a subscript but then all the associated problems with subs show up. Where's the happy medium? Thanks.

Comment: If you must: `Table[x[i][t] -> i Sin[t], {i, 1, imax}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: I realised I can use Unset.

```
Subscript[fc, 1]=.
```

Then Subscript[fc, 1] simply returns fc_1 as required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is worth reporting to support. As a workaround, you could use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block). For example, without the [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block):

```
Subscript[fc, 1]
cplots = Table[ContourPlot[Sin[Subscript[fc, i] Subscript[μ, i]],{Subscript[fc, i],0,1},{Subscript[μ, i],1,3.8}],{i,1,4}];
Subscript[fc, 1]
```

> Subscript[fc, 1]
>
> Charting`Private`pvar$23375

Using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block):

```
Clear[Subscript]
Subscript[fc, 1]
Block[{Subscript},
    cplots = Table[ContourPlot[Sin[Subscript[fc, i] Subscript[μ, i]],{Subscript[fc, i],0,1},{Subscript[μ, i],1,3.8}],{i,1,4}];
]
Subscript[fc, 1]
```

> Subscript[fc, 1]
>
> Subscript[fc, 1]